# Java parsing filename

Tags: java, parsing

Let's say I have confusing name such as `XX_10231_11_32-33-23_jsv.doc`

How do I extract only 11 from that filename?

I am currently using

```
filename.split("_", 3)[2];
```

It extracts all past 11.

Comment: Regex.. `.*?_.*?_(.*?)_.*`

Comment: @vidit the answer is `split()`.

Comment: use the split(String regex) method, without the limit. e.g. filename.split("_")[2];

Comment: Use `split` on `split` (If you insist to use `split`)

Answer (score 1):

Why not just `split("_")[2]` instead of `split("_", 3)[2]`?

```
String filename="XX_10231_11_32-33-23_jsv.doc";
System.out.println(filename.split("_")[2]);//output 11
```

---

Anyway if you want to "optimize" `split` method and stop splitting after `11`  then use `split("_", 4)`. It will produce four element array that will contain

```
["XX", "10231", "11", "32-33-23_jsv.doc"]
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is the choice of `3` for the limit.  That means that everything past the second found delimiter will be in the 3rd token.  Use a negative limit so that there is no limit to the number of tokens in the returned array.

```
filename.split("_", -1)
```

According to the [`split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) Javadocs:

> The limit parameter controls the number of times the pattern is
>   applied and therefore affects the length of the resulting array. If
>   the limit n is greater than zero then the pattern will be applied at
>   most n - 1 times, the array's length will be no greater than n, and
>   the array's last entry will contain all input beyond the last matched
>   delimiter. If n is **non-positive** then the pattern will be applied as
>   many times as possible and the array can have any length. If n is zero
>   then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible, the array
>   can have any length, and trailing empty strings will be discarded.

(emphasis mine)

Comment: Or just call `split()` without the limit parameter: `split("_")`

Comment: @iamnotmaynard Yes that would be simpler.  But I also wanted to point out what the `limit` parameter does.

Comment: Which is good, since it explains OP's results.